# Cannot modify CompositeType comparator on Cassandra column family

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Using cassandra-cli, an attempt to modify a CompositeType comparator (eg., to add or remove a field) fails with an error:

```
[default@KS] describe CF;
ColumnFamily: CF
  Cells sorted by:  
  org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType(
    org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,
    org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,
    org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)

[default@KS] truncate CF;
CF truncated.

[default@KS] update column family CF with comparator = 
'CompositeType(
   org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.LongType,
   org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type)';
comparators do not match or are not compatible.
```

An attempt to work around this by dropping and recreating the column family worked fine until restarting, apparently caused by this issue:
[cassandra Exception encountered during startup: index (1) must be less than size (1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254173/cassandra-exception-encountered-during-startup-index-1-must-be-less-than-size)

How should this case be handled properly? I suppose doing a nodetool flush after the drop would prevent issues with the commit log having incompatible data? Is there a way to modify the CompositeType comparator without doing a drop/create?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to modify the CompositeType comparator without doing a drop/create? After drop, you need do a nodetool clearsnapshot. Check this link
http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/CassandraCli08